# Mongoose: How to push in nested array?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, nosql

I am very new to NoSQL world. Here  the screenshot of my Mongoose schema.

[image: mongoose schema]

I need to insert,update and delete document to/from vehicles array.

**What I have tried so far:**

*Add: (Working)*

```
Companies.findOne({'mobile' : givenMobileNumber, 'VehicleGroups.vehicle_group_id' : vehicleGroupId}, (err, res) => {
    if( err  || res == null) {
        callback(err, res);
    }else{

        var len =  res.VehicleGroups.length;
        for(var i=0; i<len; i++)
        {
            if(res.VehicleGroups[i].vehicle_group_id == vehicleGroupId)
                res.VehicleGroups[i].vehicles.push(data);
        }
        res.save(callback);
    }
})
```

*Delete: (Working)*

```
Companies.findOneAndUpdate({ mobile : givenMobileNumber, 'VehicleGroups.vehicle_group_id' : vehicleGroupId},
{ $pull : {'VehicleGroups.$.vehicles' : { 'vehicle_id' :  vehicleId} } }, callback);
```

Still working to update data. Is my approach valid?

Thanks

Comment: You should show the community what you have tried, and where it fails. Try coming up with a minimal, complete, and verifiable example. https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @GregSchmit I have updated my question. Thanks

Comment: That's a much better question! If no one answers and you figure it out, feel free to [answer your own question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer), because the current one is not acceptable IMO. That way if others have this question, they will be more likely to find it.

Comment: @Veeram Sorry for mentioning but I am stuck.

Comment: Sorry, didn't get notified. I happen to stumble upon your post. For insert you can try `Companies.findOneAndUpdate({ mobile : givenMobileNumber, 'VehicleGroups.vehicle_group_id' : vehicleGroupId},
{ $push: {'VehicleGroups.$.vehicles' : data } }, callback);`. For updating vehicle you can use arrayFilters ( available from 3.6) `Companies.findOneAndUpdate(
   { mobile : givenMobileNumber},
   { $inc: { "VehicleGroups.$[vg].vehicles.$[v].status": "new status" } },
   { arrayFilters: [ { "vg.vehicle_group_id": vehicleGroupId } , { "v.vehicle_id":vehicleId} ], multi: true}, callback
);`

Answer (score 1):

You can consider setting up separate `schemas` for your `VehicleGroups` and `vehicles` and reference them through `ObjectId` in your `Companies` `schema`:

```
VehicleGroups: [{
  _id: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'vehicleGroup' },
  // All other properties here
  vehicles: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'vehicle' }]
}]
```

Adding a new `document` to the`VehicleGroup` `schema` would then go something like this:

```
const newVehicleGroup = new VehicleGroup({
  name: 'New Vehicle',
  // Set all other fields
})
```

And adding it to the `Companies` `schema`:

```
Companies.findOneAndUpdate({
  mobile : givenMobileNumber, 'VehicleGroups.vehicle_group_id' : vehicleGroupId,
  { $push: { vehicleGroups: newVehicleGroup._id } }
})
```

Since you reference `vehicles` and `VehicleGroups` by `ObjectId`, all you have to do to update that reference is to update the `document` in the respective `collection`.

However, if you delete a `document` you will need to remove its reference from the respective `array` in the `Companies` `collection`.

See if this approach makes it a little easier!